# PDFBOX OutOfMemory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdfbox

I am facing a big issue with PDFBOX: I tried to load a file of 10Mb (test.pdf) and i needed 400 Mb to load it on JVM: 
Here is the code sample :

```
    final File mainFile = new File(
            "C:/test.pdf");
    System.out.println("File size: " + mainFile.length());
    try {
        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(mainFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Used Memory: " +  (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));
}
```

Is that normal ?

Comment: may be it was 40MB? 400 is way too much if that is the only thing you are doing.

Comment: oh yeah. Just that. I print you all the code

Comment: At the very least, you should provide PDFBox version you are using, how you are compiling your example, what operating system you are using, etc.

Comment: I am using: PDFBOX 1.6.0

Comment: PDFBOX 1.6.0, windows 7 32 bits, and JDK 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not normal.

I notice you hadn't closed the document (required, please read the [documentation](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html)). Perhaps that accumulated in multiple runs. You also don't mention memory usage before loading the document.

Comment: A few hints can be found here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#outofmemoryrrror